# SCRIPT1006: Предполагается наличие ')' — IE

Tags: javascript, html

Здравствуйте.

```
function on_select_category(id_cat_select = false) {
  alert();
}
```

Ну хоть убей, не пойму, почему в этой функции ошибка в IE, при загрузке страницы, а при вызове ее — ваще пишет, что не найдена? :)

Comment: не смог распарсить код - не поддерживает значения параметров по умолчанию. Как результат - функция не определена.

Comment: а почему в других местах этой проблемы нет,а тут есть ? Как решить можно ?

Comment: покажите "другие места"

Comment: верно сказали ! В других местах нет "по-умолчанию"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> ```
> function on_select_category(id_cat_select = false){
> ```

IE не поддерживает ES6, дефаултьные значения не парсятся.

Надо переписать эту функцию так:

```
function on_select_category(id_cat_select){
  id_cat_select = id_cat_select === undefined ? false : id_cat_select;
  alert();
}
```

либо, если позволяет последующая логика:

```
function on_select_category(id_cat_select){
  id_cat_select = id_cat_select || false;
  alert();
}
```

впрочем, в таком случае никто не мешает спокойно пользоваться ложным `undefined`.